# Using mssql in nodejs (function to insert row)

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

So, I'm new to Nodejs, and now I am trying to make an insert, based on an action I receive from a client.

I have a functions module, which is called by the routes to make certain tasks. Each action needs to be recorded in a mssql table, so I chose to use mssql from npm.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql
```

Each function in the functions module calls the saveActionToDB function which received an action and a username to make the insert into the table like this:

```
function saveActionToDB(action, user){
    if (config.Logging.DB.type == 'mssql'){
        const dbOptions = {
            user: config.Logging.DB.user,
            password: config.Logging.DB.password,
            server: config.Logging.DB.server,
            database: config.Logging.DB.database,
            options: {
                encrypt: config.Logging.DB.encrypt
            }
        };
        const database = require('mssql');
        async () => {
            try{
                const pool = await database.connect(dbOptions);
                const result = await database.query(`insert into actions (action, user) values ("${action}", "${user}")`);
                console.log(pool);
            }
            catch (err){
                console.log(err);
                combinedLogger.error(err);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(config.Logging.DB.type == 'oracle'){
        //oracle
    }
}
```

The app needs to have the ability to use either mssql or oracle. That;s why it checks the config.Logging.DB.type val to use each of the two.

Right now, the functions call the saveActionToDB, but it doesn't do anything. No errors either. I am guessing it's an issue with the async thing.

Note that I don't need to wait for the saveActionToDB to end in order to respond to the client.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling your async function. This just declares a function but does not execute. `async () => {`

Looks at this example

```
console.log('a');
x = async () => {
  console.log('b');
}

console.log('c');
x();
```

the output is `a c b`. However if I do

```
console.log('a');
async () => {
  console.log('b');
}

console.log('c');
```

Output is just `a c`.

Comment: Oh, right. Awesome. It's still not working tho... getting an error: "Cannot find stored procedure "i" Any idea where's that coming from?

Comment: It does not look like to be coming from the above code. Its a good idea to write a new question with that particular error, stack trace and the relevant code

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!